# Connect to remote database (EC2 instance) using PHP/Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, ssh, amazon-ec2

I've got [MNPP](http://getmnpp.org/) (Nginx version of XAMPP) all set up on my Mac but can't figure how to connect to a database that isn't localhost. I've got a MySQL database on an EC2 instance that i'd like to connect to.

I'm using Codeigniter/PHP and the following configuration works:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost"; 
$db['default']['password'] = "";
```

and the following does **NOT** work:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "mysite.com"; //the name of my EC2 instance
$db['default']['password'] = "my_password";
```

I can SSH into this EC2 database using a MySQL GUI, Sequel Pro, with the above configuration and my EC2 SSH key (`~/.ssh/mysite.pem`), I just can't do it programmatically from my PHP app on my localhost.

Do I need to change anything in my my.cnf file or anywhere else to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your host is listening on TCP 3306.

You also need to set permissions for your user at your new host to be granted on the database.

On your remote database, run:

```
GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO username@'your-ip-address-here' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

Replace `your-ip-address-here` with the public IP of localhost, and username and PASSWORD with your respective values.

This will allow your application to communicate via MySQL to the remote host. These applications do not support SSH tunneling directly.

Alternatively, you could create an SSH tunnel, which will bridge your `localhost:3307` for example to `remotehost:3306`, and then in your application, you could still use localhost, but change mysql port to `3307`.

Comment: thanks, i just did this and several similar combinations: `mysql> GRANT ALL ON mysiteDB.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY ''; Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)`. Every time I got "0 rows affected" which doesn't seem right. Do I need to subsequently flush priviledges or restart mysql or something?

Comment: A flush privileges is a good idea, but also, i've never had luck when using '%' as the host, always had to specify the IP manually. Do a `SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user` and see what your current user to host is like. Depending on what you get, it would hurt to insert another user, with your specific remote host as Host, and then GRANT your new user to the database, applying the substitution to the command above.

Comment: [Here's the result](https://gist.github.com/3715773) of typing `SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user`.

Comment: Lets say your application was the entry ip-10-196-37-212. `GRANT ALL ON dbname.* TO `root`@`ip-10-196-37-212` IDENTIFIED BY `password`. When you do this successfully, you should get 1 rows affected

Comment: Oh wait, I'm typing these mysql commands on my localhost (my Mac laptop) or on my remote (the EC2 instance)?

Comment: On the database you want your application to talk to. (EC2)

Comment: hmm, how do i get the IP address of my localhost (which I assume is what you're calling "your application"? ip-10-196-37-212 is an address no longer in use. Typing: `netstat -p tcp` gives a a lot of IP addresses.

Comment: If you are not on the same lan as the EC2 instance, use, [whatismyip.com](http://whatismyip.com), otherwise on a mac you would type `ifconfig` and look for your IP on en1 or en0 (wireless vs ethernet)

Comment: ok, i just used whatismyip.com and typed this on my EC2 but it didn't work: `mysql> GRANT SELECT ON mysiteDB.* TO root@'140.247.126.90' IDENTIFIED BY '';`

Comment: Add that as a new user as well.. set user=root and host = to that IP, after it's added, rerun the grant

Comment: so on my EC2, this gives me an error: `mysql > set user=root and host = 140.247.126.90`

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't 100% valid code: `CREATE USE 'root'@'your-ip' INDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password here'` then `GRANT SELECT ON mysiteDB.* TO 'root'@'your-ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password here'`

Comment: oh man i was trying to get your last code to work and now i can't get back into mysql using this: `$ mysql -u root -p` either including my password or not.

Comment: try, `$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p`

Comment: that didn't work either, did the flush priviledges or anything else we were talking about change the login credentials?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16656/discussion-between-sixeightzero-and-tim-peterson)

Comment: thanks yes lets go to chat, I need to do something at work for 10min but I'll be right back

Comment: ok i'm back and signed on to the chatroom, i now have root access again using what you said in the link you sent, let me re-try changing my permissions now....

Comment: Hi Mike. I also get stuck on this item. Are you able to help? If so, could you open a chat to discuss? Thanks!

Comment: Actually problem is all resolved after I changed bind-address in /etc/mysql/my.cnf... Thanks anyway.